# Removing the last two or multiple words from a string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have string likely

```
select 'abc','xyz','123' Union all select 'def','wer','456' Union all
```

the string is generated by loop e.g.

```
foreach(var item in obj)
{
  " SELECT'" + item.a + "'," + item.b + ," + item.c + "UNION ALL";
}
```

Now i want to remove the `"Union all"` written in the last of the string.How can i do this is single OR using regex in C# .IndexOf wont work as i have multiple `"Union all"` in my string .

Comment: `string.LastIndexOf`. But this is a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Show us how you **generated** that string.

Comment: `if (myString.EndsWith("Union all")) myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - "Union all".Length);`

Comment: if you have a collection of `selects` you want to *join*, `Join` them: `string result = string.Join(" Union all ", selects);`

Comment: Actually i have thousands of records which i have to insert using this query .,. i could done it with BULK Insert but it does not fit my situation . what i am doing is to join the queries with "UNION ALL"  but in my last query the "UNION ALL" remians which i have to remove before executing it  .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are trying to build `finalQuery` from several `select`s; you can do it with a help of `Join`:

```
  string[] selects = new string[] {
    "select 'abc','xyz','123'",
    "select 'def','pqr','456'", 
  };

  // select 'abc','xyz','123' Union all select 'def','pqr','456' 
  string finalQuery = string.Join(" Union all ", selects);
```

If you, however, want to remove the very last `Union all` if it is, you can test the string with `EndsWith`:

```
  string finalQuery = myString.EndsWith("Union all") 
    ? myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - "Union all".Length)
    : myString;
```

**Edit:** If you generate your `selects` in a loop (see comments below), you can try *extracting method* turning `loop` into `IEnumerable<String>`:

```
   private IEnumerable<string> MySelects() {
     foreach(var item in obj) {
       // Some Logic Here...

       // When you are ready to create a select just "yield return" it and keep looping
       yield return $" SELECT '{item.a}', '{item.b}', '{item.c}'";

       // Some Other Logic Here...
     } 
   }
```

and then again `Join`:

```
   string finalQuery = string.Join(" Union all ", MySelects());
```

Finally, if you want to stick to loop (for whatever reason), add `if`:

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   foreach(var item in obj) {
     // if we have a query, next one should be add via "UNION ALL"
     if (sb.Length > 0)
       sb.Append(" UNION ALL ");

     sb.Append($"SELECT '{item.a}', '{item.b}', '{item.c}'");
   }

   string finalQuery = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: i am generating my string in a loop in which i am getting my table names and data etc .. means there is no array present .  then after string creation i am executing it but before execution it needs to remove the extra "UNION ALL"

Comment: @Haroon nasir: I suggest *extracting method* which generates the selects (with a help of `yield return`), and finally `Join` them. Please, see my edit

Comment: Yeah Sure .. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can combine `string.Join` and LINQ `Skip`:

```
string input = "select 'abc','xyz','123' Union all select 'def','wer','456' Union all";

string result = string.Join(" ", input.Split(' ').Reverse().Skip(2).Reverse());
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5TbVo8)

Comment: If we don't have any `Union all`, i.e. generating loop produces just a *single select*, e.g. `string input = "select 'abc', 'xy z', '12 3'"` (I've aggravated the matter by adding some spaces) you code will ruin the query.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko the string is generated in a loop as " SELECT'" + item.a + "'," + item.b + ," + item.c + "UNION ALL";, so "UNION ALL" is always at the end. My answer is written according to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with somelink like this. In case your replacement gets more complicated you can start using regular expressions.

```
var toRemove = "Union all";
if (yourString.EndWith(toRemove ))
{
  yourString = yourString.SubString(0, yourString.Length - toRemove.Length).Trim();
}
```

P.S. Get the toRemove string from some logical location and don't use it in your procedure like this to avoid using magic values..

Comment: Does that compile?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a function;

```
var toRemove = "Union all";

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourString))
return;

var pos = yourString.LastIndexOf(stringToFind);

 if (pos < 0) return;

string newString = yourString.Remove(pos, yourString.Length);

return newString;
```

Comment: Be careful with `LastIndexOf`: in case query is *valid*, e.g. `"select 'abc','xyz','123' Union all select 'def','pqr','456'"` (we should do nothing) your code will *ruin* it